# How to check conditions without multiple if statements?

Tags: c#, android, if-statement, dry

I am working on a game for android in Xamarin, but I have two specific sections that are extremly DRY (don't repeat yourself).

The first section is when I want to change the soundtrack(audioplay) or background, where I have three different pitches for the same soundtrack based on level, and the same for background where the background canvas alternates.

For these methods the condition is based on an integer level that equals the level the player is in.

Example code

```
private void SetBackgrounds()
{
    if (level == 5)
    {
        gameAreaCanvas.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.LevelUpOneBackground);

    }
    else if (level == 10)
    {
        gameAreaCanvas.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.LevelUpTwoBackground);

    }
    else if (level == 15)
    {
        gameAreaCanvas.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.LevelUpThreeBackground);

    }
}
```

The same goes for different parts of the code where alot is based on an integer value which is the level. Every time the player advances the level integer increments by one, and then the activity has methods that checks what the integer level is. The code is working but is very inefficient obviously, because there is a lot of duplicated code with a small tweak.

For instance a level looks like this.

```
        if(level == 1) {

            levelDisplay.Text = "LEVEL 1";
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 2000; /// DIFFERENT
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Elapsed += Level1; /// DIFFERENT
            timer.Start();
        }
        ///LEVEL 2
        if (level == 2)
        {
            levelDisplay.Text = "LEVEL 2";
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 2000; /// DIFFERENT
            timer.Enabled = true;
            timer.Elapsed += Level2; /// DIFFERENT
            timer.Start();
        }
```

Is there a way to make this code less DRY? Input is appreciated.

Comment: What about using switch cases?

Comment: FYI, setting `timer.Enabled = true;` is the same as `timer.Start();`. See: [Timer.Enabled Property documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.enabled(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @RufusL Didn't know that, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for a *dictionary*?

```
//TODO: please, check dictionary's value type
private static Dictionary<int, Resource.Drawable> s_Backgrounds = 
  new Dictionary<int, Resource.Drawable>() {
    {5, Resource.Drawable.LevelUpOneBackground},
    {10, Resource.Drawable.LevelUpTwoBackground},
    {15, Resource.Drawable.LevelUpThreeBackground},
};

...

private void SetBackgrounds() {
  gameAreaCanvas.SetBackgroundResource(s_Backgrounds[level]); 
}
```

**Edit:** same idea with `level`; the only difference is that you have *three* values that correspond to each key. The simplest solution is to organize these values into a `Tuple` (a *custom class* will be a better choice, however):

```
// I've used Tuple<string, int, int> to store three values
// you may want to change it to a custom class  
private static Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, int, int>> s_Levels = 
  new Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, int, int>>() {
    {1, new Tuple<string, int, int>("LEVEL 1", 2000, Level1)},
    {2, new Tuple<string, int, int>("LEVEL 2", 2000, Level2)},
};

...

levelDisplay.Text = s_Levels[level].Item1;
timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = s_Levels[level].Item2; /// DIFFERENT
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Elapsed += s_Levels[level].Item3; /// DIFFERENT
imer.Start();
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution! Edit: Do you have any suggestions for the levels aswell, or is switch cases the only other option?

Comment: @Eli: with a help of `Tuple<>` (custom class will be a better solution, however) you can create dictionaries for several (three in your case) values. See my edit.

Comment: I liked the first solution, but you kinda lost me with the Tuple...Maybe I need to look more into it.

Comment: @Eli: `Tuple` is a easiest (mechanic) way to combine several values; however it often looks combersome, that's why I suggest a custom class.

Answer (score 2):

The first part can be condensed as follows:

```
canvas.SetBackgroundResource( level == 5? Resource.Drawable.LevelUpOneBackground : 
                              level = 10? Resource.Drawable.LevelUpTwoBackground :
                                          Resource.Drawable.LevelUpThreeBackground );
```

Or, better yet, create a dictionary, mapping level numbers to backgrounds, so then you can have this:

```
gameAreaCanvas.SetBackgroundResource( resourcesFromLevels[level] );
```

Simplifying the second part is a bit more involved.

In cases like this, one possible solution is inheritance.

You make a new abstract `class Level` to represent a level of your game, and you create a subclass of that class for each specific level.  So, you would have `class Level1: Level`, `class Level2: Level`, and so on.  The base class has a `Setup()` method which which works by invoking overridables on itself, and each overridable has a default implementation, but descendants of `Level` can provide their own implementation.

Also, not everything has to be handled by overridables.  The `Level` class can accept some constructor parameters, like the level name, and then each descendant can supply the right level name to the base class.  So, it would look like this:

```
class Level
{
    readonly string levelName;

    Level( String levelName )
    {
        this.levelName = levelName;
    }

    void Setup()
    {
        levelDisplay.Text = levelName;
        SetupTimer();
    }

    virtual void SetupTimer()
    {
         //Default implementation
    }
}

class Level1: Level
{
    Level1() : Level( "LEVEL 1" ) 
    {
    }

    override void SetupTimer()
    {
        //Level1 implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Trying to figure out a solution to integrate the timer with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

They're called switch statements and they look like this:

```
switch(level)
{
  case 1:
    doLevel1();
    break;
  case 2:
    doLevel2();
    break;
}
```

More information can be found here: [Switch Statement Tutorial](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/switch-statement/)

Comment: This is a solution I've been looking at, but the amount of code doesn't seem to decrease. I have up to 25 levels sometimes, is the only solution to write 25 switch cases?

Comment: In your case the best solution is the switch statement, even if you have to write 25 switch cases.

Comment: @fn5341 I think in this case the best solution is by using a Map (Dictionary in C#). No switch statement, clean and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

I would make your "levels" more object-oriented:

```
public LevelObject
{
    public BackgroundResource BackgroundResource { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public double TimeInterval { get; set; }
    public double ElapsedInterval { get; set; }

    // constructors, methods, etc...
}
```

This way, you can initialize collection of "levels", like a `List<LevelObject>`, then based on your current `level`, set whatever properties as necessary:

```
int level = // current level
List<LevelObject> levelObjectList =
    new List<LevelObject>
    {
        new LevelObject("LEVEL 1", 2000, Level1),
        new LevelObject("LEVEL 2", 2000, Level2),
        // etc...
    }
LevelObject levelObject = levelObjectList[level];
```

---

Examples:

```
private void SetBackgrounds(LevelObject levelObject)
{
    if (levelObject.BackgroundResource != null)
    {
        gameAreaCanvas.SetBackgroundResource(levelObject.BackgroundResource);
    }
}
```

---

```
levelDisplay.Text = levelObject.Text;
timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = levelObject.TimeInterval;
timer.Enabled = true;
timer.Elapsed += levelObject.ElapsedInterval;
timer.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:

First of all, you need a kind of Enumeration

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
   public class MyEnumeration
   {
       #region Private Fields

       private readonly string _displayName;
       private readonly int _value;
       private readonly int _interval;
       private readonly Action _action;

       #endregion Private Fields

       #region Protected Constructors

       protected MyEnumeration()
       {
       }

       protected MyEnumeration(int value, string displayName, int interval, Action action)
       {
           _value = value;
           _displayName = displayName;
           _interval = interval;
           _action = action;
       }

       #endregion Protected Constructors

       #region Public Properties

       public string DisplayName
       {
           get { return _displayName; }
       }

       public int Value
       {
           get { return _value; }
       }

       public int Interval
       {
           get { return _interval; }
       }

       public Action Action
       {
           get { return _action; }
       }

       #endregion Public Properties

       #region Public Methods

       public static int AbsoluteDifference(MyEnumeration firstValue, MyEnumeration secondValue)
       {
           var absoluteDifference = Math.Abs(firstValue.Value - secondValue.Value);
           return absoluteDifference;
       }

       public static T FromDisplayName<T>(string displayName) where T : MyEnumeration, new()
       {
           var matchingItem = parse<T, string>(displayName, "display name", item => item.DisplayName == displayName);
           return matchingItem;
       }

       public static T FromValue<T>(int value) where T : MyEnumeration, new()
       {
           var matchingItem = parse<T, int>(value, "value", item => item.Value == value);
           return matchingItem;
       }

       public static IEnumerable<T> GetAll<T>() where T : MyEnumeration, new()
       {
           var type = typeof(T);
           var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);

           foreach (var info in fields)
           {
               var instance = new T();
               var locatedValue = info.GetValue(instance) as T;

               if (locatedValue != null)
               {
                   yield return locatedValue;
               }
           }
       }

       public int CompareTo(object other)
       {
           return Value.CompareTo(((MyEnumeration)other).Value);
       }

       public override bool Equals(object obj)
       {
           var otherValue = obj as MyEnumeration;

           if (otherValue == null)
           {
               return false;
           }

           var typeMatches = GetType().Equals(obj.GetType());
           var valueMatches = _value.Equals(otherValue.Value);

           return typeMatches && valueMatches;
       }

       public override int GetHashCode()
       {
           return _value.GetHashCode();
       }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return DisplayName;
       }

       #endregion Public Methods

       #region Private Methods

       private static T parse<T, K>(K value, string description, Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : MyEnumeration, new()
       {
           var matchingItem = GetAll<T>().FirstOrDefault(predicate);

           if (matchingItem == null)
           {
               var message = string.Format("'{0}' is not a valid {1} in {2}", value, description, typeof(T));
               throw new ApplicationException(message);
           }

           return matchingItem;
       }

       #endregion Private Methods
   }
```

}

Then you can create your own Enumeration like:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class LevelEnum : MyEnumeration
    {
        public static readonly LevelEnum Level1 = new LevelEnum(1, "Level 1", 2000, Program.Level1);
        public static readonly LevelEnum Level2 = new LevelEnum(2, "Level 2", 3000, Program.Level2);
        public static readonly LevelEnum Level3 = new LevelEnum(3, "Level 3", 4000, Program.Level3);
        public static readonly LevelEnum Level4 = new LevelEnum(4, "Level 4", 5000, Program.Level4);
        public static readonly LevelEnum Level5 = new LevelEnum(5, "Level 5", 6000, Program.Level5);
        public static readonly LevelEnum Level6 = new LevelEnum(6, "Level 6", 7000, Program.Level6);
        public static readonly LevelEnum Level7 = new LevelEnum(7, "Level 7", 8000, Program.Level7);
        public static readonly LevelEnum Level8 = new LevelEnum(8, "Level 8", 9000, Program.Level8);

        public LevelEnum()
        {
        }

        protected LevelEnum(int value, string displayName, int interval, Action action) : base(value, displayName, interval, action)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and you can use it like:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int level = 5;
    LevelEnum levelEnum = MyEnumeration.FromValue<LevelEnum>(level);

    levelDisplay.Text = levelEnum.DisplayName;
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.Interval = levelEnum.Interval;
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Elapsed += levelEnum.Action;
    timer.Start();
}

internal static void Level1()
{
    // Action for Level 1
}

internal static void Level2()
{
    // Action for Level 2
}

internal static void Level3()
{
    // Action for Level 3
}
```